# indices on nested loops?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

If I want o keep track on the id:s in a loop a convenient way to store that information in a column vector is to do something like...

```
res <- array(NA,
             dim = c(length(unique(id)),2),
             dimnames = NULL)

for (i in 1:3) {

    res[i,1] <- i

}
```

...This gives me something like:

```
i  | - |
---| --|
1  |   |
2  |   |
3  |   |
```

Now, I want to do the same thing for a nested loop so I tried:

```
res <- array(NA,
             dim = c(length(unique(id)*c(length(unique(t)),2),
             dimnames = NULL)

for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {

    res[i,1] <- i
    res[j,2] <- j


  }
}
```

But this results in:

```
i  | j |
---| --|
1  | 1 |
2  | 2 |
3  | 3 |
```

Obviously this is not what I want. Instead, it should be 3*3 rows like this:

```
i  | j |
---| --|
1  | 1 |
1  | 2 |
1  | 3 |
2  | 1 |
2  | 2 |
2  | 3 |
3  | 1 |
3  | 2 |
3  | 3 |
```

How do I get this?

Comment: `expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)`?

Comment: Not sure what we trying to achieve with loops, but how about: `expand.grid(1:3, 1:3)` ?

Comment: I want to use the loops for other stuff. I just want to keep track on the i:s and j:s

Comment: I want to put stuff into the "matrix" subsequently using a nested loop. Thus I want to keep track on the i:s and j:s (or in my case: stocks and year)

Comment: @J.AlexanderSanden If one of the answers below solved your problem please accept it by clicking the tick mark on its left.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit hacky, but I think this should work well, particularly when your iterators may become things other than integers:

```
id <- 1:9

res <- array(
  data = NA,
  dim = c(length(id), 2),
  dimnames = list(c(), c('i','j')))

k = 0
for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {

    k = k+1
    res[k,1] <- i
    res[k,2] <- j


  }
}
```

output:

```
> res
      i j
 [1,] 1 1
 [2,] 1 2
 [3,] 1 3
 [4,] 2 1
 [5,] 2 2
 [6,] 2 3
 [7,] 3 1
 [8,] 3 2
 [9,] 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you were relying on `i` being your index. Since you only have three iterations for `i`, you'll have all values for `i` while the values for `j` will be constantly overwritten.
Using a dedicated index (`ix`) solves that problem.

This should do what you want:

```
res <- data.frame(i=NULL,j=NULL)

ix <- 0
for (i in 1:3){

  for (j in 1:3){

    ix <- ix+1

    res[ix,1] <- i
    res[ix,2] <- j


  }

}
```

output:

```
> res
  V1 V2
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  2  1
5  2  2
6  2  3
7  3  1
8  3  2
9  3  3
```